# How to use Sphinx's autodoc to generate api documentation for multiple source code?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

How do we use autodoc?

I did python setup.py for both my of projects and their namespaces are importable..

I tried:

```
.. automodule:: project.backend

.. automodule:: project.api
```

But I am only getting

```
project.backend

     alias of project.backend
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use the `members` option to [automodule](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule)?

Comment: @mzjn I am afraid that;s a no :(

Comment: also add `:undoc-members:` and see what you see. But a big-picture warning: sphinx isn't a auto-generated-doc tool like doxygen/etc, if these dotted paths are actually packages with inner modules, `.. automodule::` won't recurse into them. Sphinx doesn't try (very hard) to solve the larger API auto-doccing problem, it's fundamentally oriented around human-written and maintained doc files with a structure that often diverges from the package paths. Take a look at Python's stdlib or Django docs - there's a lot of cruft/scaffolding, but that's OK. docs != code, shouldn't be organized identically.

Comment: Is `project` a namespace package?